# SharePoint Online Subsites listing 0 in WebsCount parameter

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am using the following to connect to my SPO tenant and pull a report, however I am finding that the **WebsCount** parameter is not populating any subsites, has anyone encountered similar behavior and how to fix this bulk query?

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell -DisableNameChecking

#Config Parameters
$AdminSiteURL="https://SPTenant-admin.sharepoint.com"
$ReportOutput="C:\Temp\SPOStorage.csv"

#Get Credentials to connect to SharePoint Admin Center
$Cred = Get-Credential

#Connect to SharePoint Online Admin Center
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL –Credential $Cred

#Get all Site collections details and Export to CSV
Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL -Detailed | Export-Csv -Path $ReportOutput -NoTypeInformation
```

[image: WebsCount Zero]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following PowerShell for your reference.

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Powershell -DisableNameChecking

#Config Parameters
$AdminSiteURL="https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"
$ReportOutput="C:\Temp\SPOStorage.csv"
#Get Credentials to connect to SharePoint Admin Center
$Cred = Get-Credential

#Connect to SharePoint Online Admin Center
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL –Credential $Cred

#Get All site collections
$SiteCollections = Get-SPOSite -Limit All
Write-Host "Total Number of Site collections Found:"$SiteCollections.count -f Yellow
 
#Array to store Result
$ResultSet = @()
 
#Loop through each site collection and retrieve details
Foreach ($Site in $SiteCollections)
{
    Write-Host "Processing Site Collection :"$Site.URL -f Yellow
    $Site=Get-SPOSite -identity $Site.Url -Limit ALL -Detailed
    #Get site collection details    
    $Result = new-object PSObject
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Title" -Value $Site.Title
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Url" -Value $Site.Url
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "WebsCount" -Value $Site.WebsCount
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "LastContentModifiedDate" -Value $Site.LastContentModifiedDate
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Status" -Value $Site.Status
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "LocaleId" -Value $Site.LocaleId
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "LockState" -Value $Site.LockState
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "StorageQuota" -Value $Site.StorageQuota
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "StorageQuotaWarningLevel" -Value $Site.StorageQuotaWarningLevel
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Used" -Value $Site.StorageUsageCurrent
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "CompatibilityLevel" -Value $Site.CompatibilityLevel
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "Template" -Value $Site.Template
    $Result | add-member -membertype NoteProperty -name "SharingCapability" -Value $Site.SharingCapability     
    $ResultSet += $Result
}  
  
#Export Result to csv file
$ResultSet |  Export-Csv $ReportOutput -notypeinformation
  
Write-Host "Site Quota Report Generated Successfully!" -f Green
```

Check the similar thread here: [SiteProperties.WebsCount property is returning zero (CSOM)?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203198/siteproperties-webscount-property-is-returning-zero-csom/204960)